# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

When i start my bot and type !hello in discord, I get this error, here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs,{filename[:-3]}')
client.run("*")
```

Second file example.py that is used for cogs

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class example(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot is ready')

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Hi')


async def setup(client):
    await client.add.cog(example(client))
```

I would be very happy if someone will help me to fix this problem

Comment: what version of discord.py are you using

Comment: Are you sure you are loading your cogs correctly on startup? `client.load_extension(f'cogs,{filename[:-3]}')` seems wrong, you mixed up `,` and `.`. Try adding a print statement inside the `setup` function to see if that gets executed.

Comment: It looks like you got a mistake on the last lines of your main file which is
`client.load_extension(f'cogs,{filename[:-3]}')`
as @moinierer3000 said, you got `,` and `.` mixed up. replace it with `.` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `client.add.cog` you should use `client.add_cog`.

Next time, check your code.

Here is a discord website about cogs : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html